# Issue with duplicating a node and updating attributes in dynamic website with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, dom, tampermonkey

I am trying to duplicate a node in JavaScript and update its attributes with following code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Duplicate
// @namespace
// @version      0.1
// @description
// @author       nobody
// @match        https://example.com/*
// @icon
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
'use strict';
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Script loading...");
// Select the parent element of the node to duplicate
const parentElement = document.querySelector('table');

// Function to handle cloning and modification
function cloneAndModifyNode(originalNode) {
  // Create a copy of the node
  const clonedNode = originalNode.cloneNode(true);

  // Modify the cloned node's attributes
  let clipboardText = clonedNode.getAttribute('data-clipboard-text');
  clipboardText = clipboardText.replace('#track=', 'kgm/');

  // Set the new href attribute and change the title
  clonedNode.innerHTML = `<a href="${clipboardText.replace('#track=', '/kgm/')}" target="_blank"><img src="/favicon.ico" alt="Save"></a>`;
  clonedNode.setAttribute('class', 'share_twitter');
  clonedNode.setAttribute('title', 'Download');

  // Remove the data-clipboard-text attribute
  clonedNode.removeAttribute('data-clipboard-text');

  // Insert the cloned node after the original node
  originalNode.parentNode.insertBefore(clonedNode, originalNode.nextSibling);
}

// Function to handle updates when the website changes dynamically
function handleDynamicUpdates(event) {
  // Check if the target element is td.direct_link or its descendant
  if (event.target.matches('td.direct_link, td.direct_link *')) {
    // Get the original node
    const originalNode = event.target.closest('td.direct_link');

    // Check if the cloned node already exists
    const clonedNode = originalNode.nextElementSibling;
    if (clonedNode && clonedNode.classList.contains('share_twitter')) {
      // Update the attributes of the existing cloned node
      cloneAndModifyNode(clonedNode);
    } else {
      // Create a new cloned node
      cloneAndModifyNode(originalNode);
    }
  }
}

// Add event listener to the parent element
parentElement.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', handleDynamicUpdates);

// Call the cloning and modification function initially for existing nodes
const originalNodes = document.querySelectorAll('td.direct_link');
originalNodes.forEach(cloneAndModifyNode);

        console.log("Node cloned. Ready.");
    }, 3000);
})();
```

The code is intended to duplicate a node from a dynamic website and update its attributes, specifically the `href` attribute. However, the new link from the duplicated node is not being updated correctly with the new `data-clipboard-text` and only retaining the previous data from the whole page reload.

While there doesn't seem to be an issue with duplicating the node itself or the other attributes, the new link (the `href` attribute) of the duplicated node is not being updated correctly

Was expecting the node to update with the latest link from `data-clipboard-text`.